# Is it possible to overwrite the Prompt function from a function in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, prompt

I'm trying to define a single command to set a custom prompt on the PowerShell console.
You can overwrite the default prompt with the following script:

```
function Prompt {
    "PS " + "[$(Get-Date)] " + $(Get-Location) + ">"
}
```

So I would like to call above script with a function, e.g.: `Set-CustomPrompt`.

I've already seen a solution on StackOverflow where the script was executed from an external ps1 file, but I am looking for a solution where the definition is in the same file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have your `Set-CustomPrompt` function define the `Prompt` function in the [global scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-3.0) ([see also](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-3.0)):

```
function Set-CustomPrompt {
    function global:Prompt {
        "PS [$(Get-Date)] $(Get-Location)>"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `prompt` function needs to be an global scope. But it can call another function.

So define with a level of abstraction with a global variable holding the function name:

```
function Set-CustomPrompt {
   ....
   $myCustomPropmtFunctionName = ...
}

function prompt {
    &$myCustomPropmtFunctionName;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just defining the prompt function in your code doesn't work for you?
(see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts?view=powershell-5.1)